# Left adjoint to the tensor functor

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, adjoint-functors

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $k$.

Define $V \otimes - :$ Vect $\to$ Vect the tensor endofunctor on the category of $k$ vector spaces.

**Assume** that $V \otimes - $ preserves limits. It can be shown using an adjoint functor theorem that it has a left adjoint $F \dashv V\otimes-$.

It is known that every vector space $W$ can be written as a colimit of $k$, namely that $W \cong \oplus_{i \in I}k$ where a basis of $W$ is indexed by $I$.

> Show that $F$ is given by tensoring with some vector space.

Now, the way I understand this question is that we're trying to prove that for any vector space $W$, $F(W) = W \otimes V_W$, for some vector space.
Maybe they mean something stronger, that $F(W) = W \otimes Z$ for all $W$.

In order to prove something like that I'd need to find a canonical map $\phi: W \times V_W \to F(W)$ with the universal property of tensor products. However I'm not seeing where such a map may come from. The universality can maybe follow after that by using the fact the $F$ must preserve colimits, and so $F(W)$ is a colimit as well.

I also have this information:

Hom$(F(W), Z) \cong$ Hom$(W, V\otimes Z)$ for any two vector spaces $Z,W$ - though this doesn't seem to supply such a map.

Any guidance?

Comment: Is this even true?  If tensoring is a right adjoint then it preserves all limits/products, which usually isn’t true.

Comment: A field is flat, @Randall, so tensoring is left exact over a field, or am I missing something

Comment: I’m sure things are fine for finite limits.  Tensoring doesn’t usually respect, eg, infinite direct products. @Card_Trick

Comment: @Randall the right adjoint here preserves limits iff $V$ is finite dimensional. According to a later clause in this question.

Comment: I didn’t see that $V$ is fd.

Comment: @Randall I guess we're not assuming it for this part of the question, though. The above should be true in any case, assuming that $ V \otimes -$ preserves limits, and has a left adjoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get started, the claim is indeed that $F$ must be given by tensoring with a fixed vector space $V^*$. Now if $W$ is a vector space of dimension $\kappa$, then $F(W)$ is the sum of $\kappa$ copies of $F(k)$. This is the same as $W\otimes F(k)$! Indeed, every cocontinuous endofunctor of vector spaces $F$ is naturally isomorphic, by the composition $F(W)\cong \oplus_\kappa F(k)\cong F(k)\otimes W$, to tensoring with $F(k)$, and I hope this is enough to get you going on the full proof. So the involvement of $V$ is a red herring here.

Comment: Hey Kevin, thank you! Can you provide a reference to why $\oplus_{\kappa}F(k) \cong W \otimes F(k)$? I guess I'm lacking some knowledge about tensor products..

Comment: @Mariah Well, the simplest reason is that tensoring preserves colimits, as it has a right adjoint, namely hom. This is a very important fact, so I'd suggest proving it for yourself if it's unfamiliar, although it's also possible to show that tensoring preserves coproducts by an explicit manipulation with bases.

Answer (score 3):

$V \otimes (-)$ has a left adjoint if and only if $V$ is finite-dimensional; for one direction see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3053641/232). In the finite-dimensional case we have a natural isomorphism

$$V \otimes (-) \cong \text{Hom}(V^{\ast}, -)$$

and then by the usual tensor-hom adjunction, the left adjoint (naturally in $V$) is $V^{\ast} \otimes (-)$.

In the general case of modules the condition is that if $M$ is an $(R, S)$-bimodule then $M \otimes_S (-)$ has a left adjoint if and only if $M$ is finitely presented projective as a right $S$-module, in which case its left adjoint is given by tensoring with $\text{Hom}_S(M, S)$ over $R$; see [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/10/26/dualizable-objects-and-morphisms/).

Comment: More generally, tensoring with a module preserves products if and only if the module is finitely presented, so this is a necessary condition for the tensor functor to have a left adjoint.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) We're not assuming $V$ is finite dimensional here though. They intend us to show that $F$ is given by tensoring using the assumption that $V \otimes - $ preserves limits, hence has a left adjoint, and by using the fact that every vector space is a colimit of the field.Do you know how to approach this with these assumptions?

Comment: @Mariah: I'm not assuming it. It's a consequence of the assumption that $V \otimes (-)$ preserves limits. If you really don't want to use this fact, you can instead prove that every colimit-preserving endofunctor of $\text{Vect}$ (in particular every left adjoint) is given by tensoring with some vector space.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan This last part of your comment is what I hoped to receive an answer to: why is $F$ given by tensoring. I'm not given, and cannot yet assume, that $V$ is finite dimensional. I need to use the fact the $V \otimes -$ preserves limits, hence has a left adjoint, and that we can write any vector space $W$ as a colimit of the field. Can you assist in helping me find out why such a functor is given by tensoring?

Comment: Every vector space is a coproduct of copies of the underlying field $k$ (given by picking a basis) and a colimit-preserving functor preserves this coproduct.